# Reset partial date to a default complete date in R

Tags: r, date

I'm a beginner using dates in R and would like to complete partial dates in my string. For example I have the following dates:

```
x<- as.Date(c("2000-01-07", "2000", "2000-11"), format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

I would like to take dates with missing months and set them to June, and dates with missing days and set them to the 15th. It would look like this:

```
x<- as.Date(c("2000-01-07", "2000-06-15", "2000-11-15"), format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

I am trying this but I'm not sure how it works:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
mutate(Date = as.Date(x)) %>%
complete(Date = seq.Date(15), by="day"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a regex to change it to full Date format before applying the `as.Date`

```
v2 <- sub("^(\\d{4}-\\d{2})$", "\\1-15", sub("^(\\d{4})$", "\\1-06-15", v1))
as.Date(v2)
#[1] "2000-01-07" "2000-06-15" "2000-11-15"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("2000-01-07", "2000", "2000-11")
```